iPhone photos/videos recovery after deletion
There was a Windows file loss of important pictures and videos which had manually been transferred from an iphone 6s to windows.
What tool for an iPhone 4 and an iPhone 6s is best to retrieve the photos and videos?

The photos have been deleted from the iPhones right?

Using the word "best" in the title risks this question being flagged or closed for opinion reference, disallowed in SE. Consider to simply remove the words in the title and question. You may yet get closed as there is https://apple.stackexchange.com/

You could try Pic Restore: Photo Recovery. No idea how effective it is though, to be honest, as I never owned or will own an iPhone. But I see it recommended here and there by various users on many websites.
Just answering to mainly let you know that you should try any kind of solution ASAP. Asking and waiting for answers minimizes the likelihood of recovery by a lot, especially if you don't have high disk space remaining on the device. As every time anything happens, the free space gets overwritten by logs, databases like phone calls or texts, etc., leading to removing any trail about the photos. Speed of actions is always most important for recovery. Use a local recovery service if the photos were very important.
